# Discontinuities of monotone operators on arbitrary spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, continuity

Let $X$ be a vector space equipped with an inner product $\langle .,.\rangle$.

A function $f:X\rightarrow X$ is said to be monotone if, for all $x,y$, $\langle f(x)-f(y),x-y\rangle\geq 0$.

On $\mathbb{R}$, such functions can have only atmost countable number of discontinuities. Further, they have to be jump discontinuities.

Can we say something similar about other spaces?
I have been trying this for $\mathbb{R}^n$, without any results so far.

To make the problem simpler for infinite dimensions, maybe consider just linear monotone operators on Hilbert spaces.

Comment: In higher dimensions we cannot expect "at most countable number of discontinuities". For example, consider
$
f(x_1,x_2)=(x_1+x_1/|x_1|,x_2)$; $f(0,x_2)=(0,x_2)$
which is a monotone map on $\mathbb R^2$. Every point of the form $(0,x_2)$ is a point of discontinuity, and this is an uncountable set. ¶ But you could ask if the set of discontinuities is • of zero Lebesgue measure (in finite dimensions); or • of 1st category (which makes sense in general). I think the answer will be yes in both cases, and already exists in the literature, but I do not have a reference yet.

Comment: of course! i dont know what i was thinking.... any monotone function $f$ on $\mathbb{R}$ with a discontinuity will give you a function $(x_1,x_2)\rightarrow (f(x_1),x_2)$ with uncountably many discontinuities.

Answer (score 0):

A result is available when $X$ is a real Hilbert space and $f$ is *maximally monotone*, i.e., the graph of $f$ cannot be enlarged without destroying monotonicity. Indeed, we have

**Kenderov's Theorem.**

Suppose $f$ is maximally monotone on the real Hilbert space $X$. Assume that the interior of the domain of $f$ (the points where $f(x)\neq\varnothing$) is nonempty.

Then there exists a subset $C$ of the interior of the domain of $f$ that is a dense $G_\delta$ subset of the closure and such that for every $c\in C$, the set $f(c)$ is a singleton and every selection of $f$ is continuous at $c$.

The proof is nontrivial and can be found in Chapter 21 of the book by Bauschke and Combettes.